# GCM send message to multiply devices

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

As part of using the GCM interface, one's server needs to use this format in order to send a msg to the GCM server (which will pass the data to the devices):

```
headers = { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'key=' + GCM_KEY }
values = { 'registration_ids': [regId], 'data': {'msg': 'helo'} }
```

Where: GCM_KEY is my server key and regId is a string of registration IDs delimited by ','.

Say user A has registration ID of 1 and user B has registration ID of 2.

When I try to send a message to only one device, e.g user A, regId equals to the string '1' and the message passes correctly. Same thing happens when I try to pass the message to User 2 only.

But when I try to send the message to both devices, regId = '1,2', the message just won't pass (by GCM documentation, a success is when the response contains 0 failures and 0 canonical_ids, and so I'm getting something different than a successful response).

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The entire payload is JSON, so the regId array needs to be a JSON array. Instead of `'1,2'` use `["1","2"]`.

Comment: But I put regId inside the values already inside brackets [regId]... so it should be just as you say. or if im wrong could you please show me the correct way?

Comment: regId is either a string or an array of strings. If you sent regId as `[1,2]`, that's an array of numbers. Double-check exactly what you're sending to GCM, and validate that JSON at http://jsonlint.com.